# how to filter/trim a particular variable value in ansible

Tags: shell, ansible, ansible-facts

I have a requirement where I have to extract/filter particular length of a string in ansible. For example:-

My node machine has following hostname:- jpujenkins, jpunessus.

So in fact variable we will have.

{{ ansible_hostname }} --> jpujenkins.

{{ ansible_hostname }} --> jpunessus

But I want to remove first three letter say 'jpu' from the all node hostname.

Desired output :- jenkins, nessus

Also can be capitalize the letter say JENKINS, NESSUS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `regex_replace` Ansible filter to fulfill your need.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters

For example, my hostname is `ip-192-168-1-65`.

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ ansible_hostname | regex_replace('^ip-', '') }}"
```

When I execute the playbook it returns the hostname where `'^ip-'` part is replaced with an empty string `''`.

```
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Tuesday 28 April 2020  11:18:24 +0300 (0:00:07.281)       0:00:07.498 *********
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: 192-168-1-65
```